# Return values in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

My program is returning values in single array: ["addEcommerceItem", "hat", 29.99, "addEcommerceItem", "belt", 19.99];

I am trying to acheive (["addEcommerceItem", "hat", 29.99], ["addEcommerceItem", "belt", 19.99]);

Can anyone make suggestion

```
products = [
    ["hat", 29.99],
    ["belt", 19.99]
]

var testArray = new Array();

for(i in products){
    testArray.push('addEcommerceItem');
    testArray.push(products[i]);
}

var json = JSON.stringify(testArray);

<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  _paq.push(json);
</script>
```

Comment: You really should remove those `productid =` and `price =` assignments from your array literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [don't use `for in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Now, there are two ways of approaching the result you want. First, you can simply alter the existing array by prepending that item to every of them:

```
for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++)
    products[i].unshift("addEcommerceItem");

console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
```

If that's not what you want, you would construct a new array rather:

```
var _paq = […]; // somewhere

for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++)
    _paq.push(["addEcommerceItem"].concat(products[i]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(_paq));
```

Instead of the `concat`, you could of course use a second loop:

```
var _paq = […]; // somewhere

for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i],
        temp = [];
    temp.push("addEcommerceItem";
    for (var j=0; j<product.length; j++)
        temp.push(product[j]);
    _paq.push(temp); // push each array individually
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(_paq));
```

Comment: All I want is inside the _paq.push( [ ], [ ] ); NOT _paq.push( [ [ ], [ ] ] );
Even though "addEcommerceItem" appears to be a string it is a function from another program that includes the wrapper [ ]. That is why nested arrays will not work in this case.

Comment: Please look again. What I my code does **is** `_paq.push( [ ], [ ] )`! There is no other nesting except `_paq` itself! It's only the wrapper array that comes with your "function"!

Comment: Please look at the original code above. What you are saying is not true. Post on JS Bin. _paq is an empty array [ ]. Your code outputs [ [ ], [ ] ]. (Try it!) So in theory what you are actually producing is [ [ [ ], [ ] ] ]. That is why the output needs to be [ ], [ ] only so that it _paq.push( [ ], [ ] ); like so.

Comment: as you mentioned above I don't think JSON.stringify will work here because it will never show two structures next to each other

Comment: Here is an example of what you are essentially outputting: [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/cipaneyada/1/edit?html,console)

Comment: I posted your code [here](http://jsbin.com/necofiduga/1/edit?html,console) so you can see what the issue is. I changed your variable name.

Comment: Please read my answer again. It doesn't use a separate `emptyArray`, but pushes to `_paq` directly!

Comment: Hi Bergi, see [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/bidoqihoxu/1/edit?html,console) here. A circular object Array is returned..

Comment: No wonder when you do `_paq.push(_paq);`… but that's not what the code in my answer does.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion. This the way I need it to work unfortunately. I need that value in the _paq.push( ); to be just [ ], [ ]. It's quite a pain!

Comment: @Jgunzblazin: there is no such value that acts as two values. You need to push in a loop, or use `apply`. What are the actual constraints for your script that pushes to `_paq`, and where do they come from?

Comment: yes that's why I changed your variable name in the previous JS BIN above. The constraints are to push non-nested arrays. The secondary script is provided from a 3rd party collecting information. That's why "addEcommerceItem" works as a function. [Look here](http://piwik.org/docs/ecommerce-analytics/#ecommerce-tracking) to see the documentation.

Comment: Oh  come on that can't be so hard to understand: http://jsbin.com/feyuyojuyi/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired output, I've modified the `for-loop` to `splice` in the additional value to the `products` array instead of pushing it to the `testArray`.

```
var testArray = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++){
    products[i].splice(0,0,'addEcommerceItem');
    testArray.push(products[i]);
}
```

A JS Bin demonstrating the results can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/komuremole/1/edit?html,console).

Comment: hmm, no good, this returns: [Array[0], Array[0], Array[2], "addEcommerceItem", Array[2]]

Comment: I've created [this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/foyucidove/1/edit?html,console) to demonstrate the results I'm seeing.  Can you show me how you are getting your results?

Comment: You are right. I keyed it incorrectly. However this produces multi-dimensional array:[ ["addEcommerceItem", "hat", 29.99], ["addEcommerceItem", "belt", 19.99]];

I am trying to acheive: 
       ( ["addEcommerceItem", "hat", 29.99], ["addEcommerceItem", "belt", 19.99]);

Comment: so basically ( [ ], [ ] );

Comment: Ah, I see.  I misread your OP thinking multi-dimensional was your intention.  That was my oversight.

Comment: @Jgunzblazin I've modified my original answer to hopefully correct the issue.

Comment: your JS Bin returns: [["addEcommerceItem", "hat", 29.99], ["addEcommerceItem", "belt", 19.99]] which is still nested.

Answer (score 0):

Just write what you want to happen: replace each sub-array with its elements preprended by `"addEcommerceItem"`. You could use `concat` for that:

```
function prepend(item) { return ["addEcommerceItem"] . concat(item); }
```

Or, if you prefer,

```
function prepend(item) { item.unshift("addEcommerceItem"); return item; }
```

Then it's just

```
function transform(products) { return products . map(prepend); }
```

Sample usage:

```
>> products = [ ["hat", 29.99], ["belt", 19.99] ]
>> transform(products)
<< [ ["addEcommerceItem","hat",29.99], ["addEcommerceItem","belt",19.99] ]
```

To call `_paq.push` with each item in the resulting array as one argument, then

```
_paq.push.apply(_paq, transform(products))
```

In ES6:

```
var prepend   = item     => ["addEcommerceItem", ...item];
var transform = products => products . map(prepend);

_paq.push(...transform(products));
```

Comment: what a headache for me. I am not trying to create nested array. I need to push separate array into variable like so: _paq.push( [ ], [ ] );

Comment: Your expression "push separate array into variable" is extremely hard to understand. Do you mean to do `_pag.push.apply(_paq, transform(products))`?

Comment: Bergi hit the nail on the head. I am simply trying to add array objects to _paq.push( );